# Running python code from a text file into your python program

Tags: python

I Want to save my python code as a text file then make a python launcher that once you log in the program starts executing code from the text file. Is This possible to do and if so can someone please help

Comment: Is it possible to get python to read command from a text file and run those commands

Comment: Hi, I've written an answer for you, @26099...
Is it useful?
If so, please, upvote it and mark it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is a bit obscure but if I got it right you want create a python script that is able to launch other python scripts.

I do not understand the use of this but here's a possible solution, keeping in mind that your "text file" was saved as "yourscript.py":

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "yourscript.py"])
```

This code will act like if you'd run the saved "yourscript.py" from the command line.

Comment: These code does not work on my computer as i have no admin rights

Comment: What kind of error do you get?
Can you run the script manually if you have no admin rights?
@26099

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html), e.g.:

```py
import runpy
runpy.run_path("yourscript.py", init_globals={'global_name':some_value})
```

With optional `init_globals` parameter you can control global objects within the runtime of the script you are calling.